# Stream issue in file extension

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I use CrystalReports 13 (13.0.7) in an ASP.NET 4.5.1 application.
I need to export report in HTML because i want a static report page, without reportviewer.

If i try the following code:

```
MemoryStream oStream; // using System.IO
oStream = (MemoryStream)
rd.ExportToStream(
CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.HTML40);
```

Application generates an error (Detail: Couldn't find file "name.htm".) as it saves the file in temp folder as name.html.

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure that `ExportToStream` returns a `MemoryStream` and not a `Stream` ?

Comment: I have tried both the ways. According to me `ExportFormatType` saves the file as `.html` while `ExportToStream` looks for a `.htm` file extension.
Correct me if i am wrong.